# How could I drag a tableview from up to down and fire an action then?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have in mind following behaviour for my table view controller. It is a table view to show to do items, just like a tasks list. I want to know if it where possible to drag down the whole table view and hold it in this position, and while in this position the user could enter a voice command that should be stored as a sound file in a core data entity.
Any proposals and help is welcome.

Comment: do you mean "pull down and hold down" like pull-to-refresh in the email app?

Comment: I don't know the email app, I mean to pull down and hold the table view down until the user leaves this action. I think that in a better english the action is called to pull down and hold...thank you

Comment: I think you should check this out: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: this will show you how to detect the bounce: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853946/uiscrollview-bounce-test

Comment: Thank you @NeverHopeless, and do you know any example or tutorial using this class in a tableView?

Comment: Thank you @katzenhut, I will check this post right now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a project that implement PullRefresh, but you can use this to do another stuff.

Take a look to [EGOTableViewPullRefresh](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh)

Comment: I will check using UIScrollView methods.Thank you